# Reason for using trunc function on dates in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am currently working in a project on a Oracle database. I have observed in the application code that dates are almost never used directly. Instead, they are always used in conjunction with the trunc function (TRUNC(SYSDATE), TRUNC(event_date), etc.)

Can anyone explain the reason behind using the trunc function instead of using the date directly?

Comment: Because a `DATE` in Oracle also contains a time part. I guess the developers want to make sure that this time is ignored when comparing with "real" dates

Comment: TRUNC() also accepts optional arguments for resetting other date components as well [See here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `DATE` in Oracle has not only a date part, but also a time part. This can lead to surprising results when querying data, e.g. the query

```
with v_data(pk, dt) as (
  select 1, to_date('2014-06-25 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  select 2, to_date('2014-06-26 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all  
  select 3, to_date('2014-06-27 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') from dual)
select * from v_data where dt = date '2014-06-25'
```

will return no rows, since you're comparing to 2014-06-25 at midnight.

The usual workaround for this is to use `TRUNC()` to get rid of the time part:

```
with v_data(pk, dt) as (
  select 1, to_date('2014-06-25 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all
  select 2, to_date('2014-06-26 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') from dual union all  
  select 3, to_date('2014-06-27 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh24:mi:ss') from dual)
select * from v_data where trunc(dt) = date '2014-06-25'
```

Other, somewhat less frequently used approaches for this problem include:

- convert both dates with `to_char('YYYY-MM-DD')` and check for equality
- use a between clause: `WHERE dt between date '2014-06-25' and date '2014-06-26'`

Answer (score 2):

You use the `trunc()` function to remove the time component of the date.  By default, the `date` data type in Oracle stores both dates and times.

The `trunc()` function also takes a format argument, so you can remove other components of the dates, not just the time.  For instance, you can trunc to the nearest hour.  However, without the format, the purpose is to remove the time component.

Answer (score 0):

If you the column in your table, for example event_date, is indexed, then avoid using trunc on the column because if you do that then Oracle can't use the index (otherwise, you can create a function based index)

so do not do:

select *
from mytable
where trunc(event_date) < date '2014-01-01'

but instead do

select *
from mytable
where event_date < date '2014-01-02'

In the second case, Oracle can do a range scan on the index on event_date, in the first case it has to do a full table scan.